# How to model NoSQL databases (Firestore)? Review my first approach

Tags: database, typescript, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I try to model my first NoSQL database (Firestore) for an application which reflects the decisions of democratic organizations (e.g. parties) about ideas.

Therefore, I would be really grateful if you could review my NoSQL concept and give me tips on how to improve it. If you like the idea and if you would like to support the project, check out the git-repo:
https://github.com/Donnerstagnacht/leftlife

**So, I thought about a model of the democratic idea with the following attributes:**

```js
    // attributes of the idea
    ideaID: string;
    location: string;
    image: string;
    video: string;
    text: string;
    hashtags?: Object[];
    date?: string;
```

**Users can do the following operations now:**

1. Like the Idea
2. Share the Idea
3. Add Comments
4. Add Proposals
5. Groups can support an idea

**The Users and the app will also regularly do the following operations:**

1. User searches for IdeaNames (SearchComponent)
2. User searches for IdeaHashtags (SearchComponent)
3. User searches for all ideas during a time span (SearchComponent)
4. App asks for all ideas of a certain event (EventComponent)
5. App asks for all ideas of a certain person (ProfileComponent)
6. App asks for all ideas of a certain group (GroupComponent)
7. App asks for ideas with most likes
8. App asks for ideas with the most supportive Groups

**To render the idea view completely, I have to retrieve different pieces of information about:**

1. The Author
2. The comments
3. The proposals
4. The events
5. The likes
6. The supporting groups

**Having that in my mind, I thought to create 6 collections:**

1. Ideas Collection
2. User Collection
3. Comment Collection
4. Proposal Collection
5. Event Collection
6. Group Collection

**...to do the following queries to render the view of the IdeaComponent**

```js
 // the idea has an author
    // query idea collection to retrieve
    userID: string;
    userName: string;
    userImage: string;

    // user can add comments
    // query comment collection to retrieve
    commentID: string;
    commentText: string;
    commentAuthorName: string; // userName
    commentAuthorID: string; // userID
    commentAuthorImage: string; // userImage

    // user can add proposals how to change the idea
    // query proposal collection to retrieve
    proposalID: string;
    proposalText: string;
    proposalAuthorName: string; // userName
    proposalAuthorID: string; // userID
    proposalAuthorImage: string; // userImage

    // user discuss the idea at real life events
    // query event collection to retrieve
    eventID: string;
    eventAuthorName: string;
    eventAuthorID: string;
    eventAuthorImage: string;

    // user can like the idea
    // query user collection to retrieve
    userID: string;
    userName: string;
    userImage: string;

    // groups can support the idea
    // query groups collection to retrieve
    groupID: string;
    groupName: string;
    groupImage: string;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to model your data:

#### 1 Directly from Firestore

Check the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

#### 2 From your code

i.e.: I'd removed ideaID because it will be generated automatically.

```
export interface IdeaModel {
    location: string;
    image: string;
    video: string;
    text: string;
    hashtags?: Array<string>;
    date?: Date;
}
```